# Pentaho Data integartion database connections

Tags: pentaho-spoon

I have a question about Pentaho Data Integration (Community)
I am creating a transformation and I create a database connection to a MySQL database. The connection works well, but when I create a second transformation and I am using a database step I can't select the database connection that I have created for the first transformation.
It seems like a database connection is related to a transformation, but how can I create a database connection for all objects of my session?
For example, I can select AgileBI (the connection of the installation) from every transformation or jobs

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that you have not shared the connection, go to connection, right click and share, after you do this any transformation can use the shared connection, regards

Answer (score 0):

What we did is, when defining the connection in transformation, we use environment variables, etc. ${HOSTNAME} ${DATABASENAME}, we end up with many transformations having their own connections, but each connection is the same. Then we give value to the variable. 
This solution doesn't share connections, but it share connection variables or parameters.